# Access Namespace Classes through Include Statements

Tags: php

Consider a typical controller layout:

```
namespace app\UserBundle\Controller;

use app\Common\Utils\Utils;

class Controller {
    function someAction() {
        $this->render('path.php');
    }

    function render($path) {
        include ($path);
    }
}
```

where path.php uses `Utils`. Is there a way to keep the same namespace context when including? Or what's the proper approach here? `path.php` is supposed to just be a template file which controls layout - I'd much rather not have namespaces or use statements there.

i.e. `path.php` contains

```
<div>the time is <?=Utils::niceTime(now())?></div>
```

Comment: How about using `\app\Common\Utils\Utils::niceTime(now());` in path.php?

Comment: I guess I just wanted to avoid that, but if there's no alternative, then... oh well.

Comment: I think if you don't have `echo` in your `niceTime()` you can assign it to a variable in the `render` method and just echo it the variable in `path.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [class_alias](http://php.net/class_alias) for Utils class.

P.S. there is no similar function for namespace.